# Program looking for msvcp140D.dll instead of msvcp120D.dll

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, windows-10

Before you say that this is a duplicate question, I have tried everything I could find on stackoverflow and Microsoft forums but none of them worked for me. I have Visual Studio 2013 installed on my Windows 10 machine. My project's target and platform versions say V 12 but when I try to open the executable, it tries to find msvcp140D.dll instead of msvcp120D.dll
How do I make it get the msvcp120D.dll? 
I have both the 2015 and 2013 C++ distributables installed.
I also tried to change the code generation properties to /mT and /mTD but it gives a lot of errors when I do that. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is you application using any other third-party dependency? One or more debug versions of third-party library could be looking for that DLL

Comment: Get Dependency Walker and look at what your program and anything it uses depends on.

Comment: Yes, I checked the target and platform versions of every dependency and it says v 12. I also downloaded the C++ 2015 distributables, I can see those "missing" files in C:\Windows\System32. Not sure why it's not finding them when they are there